# Is it possible to access crash logs stored on iPhone through my app?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, crash, logging

Is it possible to access crash logs and console logs stored on iPhone through my app?

If so, how can i do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can access them through the device organizer in the dev tools.  They'll be available even if the phone is not a registered development device for you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Am already aware of this feature, just wanted to check if this can be done programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [PLCrashReporter](http://code.google.com/p/plcrashreporter/).  It does just that, but you do need to upload the crash logs somewhere, then desymbolicate them. Just a warning, this does override the default crash reporting to Apple, so be careful shipping an app with this in it.